# Getting the higher order bytes from an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, casting

I have an a numpy array of 32bit integers and I want to convert it to 16bit integers.

I can easily do this using astype however it appears that this always selects the LSBytes while I am interested in the MSBs

```
a=np.array([65536],dtype=np.int32)

a.astype(np.uint16)
>>> array([0], dtype=uint16)
```

I can get what I want by doing a right shift first as such:

```
np.right_shift(a,16).astype(np.uint16)
>>> array([1], dtype=uint16)
```

but this seems rather inefficient.

I have read the documentation on astype and tried all of the casting options but nothing does what I am looking for.

Comment: Why do you think it should be inefficient? Bitshifts are extremly fast.

Comment: In your example, `a` has type `np.int32`, which is signed, but you are converting to `np.uint16`, which is unsigned.  Is that exactly how you want to handle negative numbers?

Comment: @Eric - the bitshift would be inefficient inefficient in this case because there would be an extra memory allocation to hold the memory of the bitshift - assuming I want to preserve the original data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a 16 bit "view" of the 32 bit array, and then use a slice to view just the higher order word.

For example, in `a`, the lower 16 bits contain 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, and the higher 16 bits contain 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7:

```
In [47]: a = np.arange(0, 8, dtype=np.int32)*2**16 + np.arange(10, 18, dtype=np.int32)

In [48]: a
Out[48]: array([    10,  65547, 131084, 196621, 262158, 327695, 393232, 458769], dtype=int32)
```

`b` is an array of 16 values containg the higher 16 bits from `a`.  (This assumes the byte order is [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).)

```
In [49]: b = a.view(np.uint16)[1::2]

In [50]: b
Out[50]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=uint16)
```

Because the `.view()` method and slices to not copy the array's data, `b` is a view into the same memory buffer as `a`.  If you change `b` in-place, you will also change `a`.

Note that this does not round the numbers.  The high 16 bits of the 32 bit number 65535 will be 0.

Also, this might not handle negative values the way that you want.

Comment: I came up with a similar solution `np.frombuffer(np.getbuffer(a),dtype=np.uint16)[1::2]` but yours is much cleaner and timeit says nearlytwice as fast. Thanks

Comment: Nice. I tried with `dtype` and `offset` but didn't achieve anything. Do you know if it would be possible as well?

Comment: @Techniquab I ran a few timing tests on the solution. While both the *view* and the *buffer* approach do not seem to depend on the array size, the *view* is slightly faster (presumably less overhead). `rightshift` indeed gets slower with increasing array size.

Comment: @EricDuminil I think you would still need to use a `.view(...)` at some point.